# how to add php code in .tpl type of file in cs-cart

Tags: php, cs-cart

can anyone tell me how to add php code in .tpl file e.g i want to add the following code but it didn't work

```
{php}
    if(isset($_GET['redirect']) && $_GET['redirect']=='clipboard'){

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check" value="redirect" />' ;

 } 
 else{

     echo '<input type="hidden" name="check" value="notredirect" />' ;
 }

{/php}
```

Comment: There is no reason ever to read `$_GET` from template

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="check" value="{if $smarty.get.redirect != "clipboard"}not{/if}redirect" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set:

```
'allow_php_in_templates' => true, // Allow to use {php} tags in templates
```

in your `config.local.php`, and then it will work.